# puppet ignores ENC classes

Tags: puppet

I am using a ruby script to retrieve the class parameters and my YAML output is as below:

```
classes:
  tomcat_install:
    tmp_dir: /tmp
    tomcat_home: /tmp/tomcat6
```

`puppet.conf` is as below:

```
[master]
node_terminus = exec
external_nodes = /etc/puppet/readnodedefinitions.rb
```

When I give the test command from puppet agent the log is:

```
Notice: Ignoring --listen on onetime run
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for puppet-agent
Info: Applying configuration version '1367987990'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.06 seconds
```

But the classes specified in ruby script are getting ignored. Any idea why its ignored?

debug mode gave this

```
Debug: Finishing transaction 69977541744660
Debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Debug: node supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate for puppet-agent.cs1cloud.internal
Debug: Using cached certificate_revocation_list for ca
Info: Retrieving plugin
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
Debug: Finishing transaction 69977541525360
Debug: catalog supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml dot pson raw yaml; using pson
Info: Caching catalog for puppet-agent.cs1cloud.internal
Debug: Creating default schedules
Debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1367987990'
Debug: /Schedule[daily]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[monthly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[hourly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[never]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[weekly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[puppet]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: Finishing transaction 69977541711700
Debug: Storing state
Debug: Stored state in 0.03 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.07 seconds
Debug: Value of 'preferred_serialization_format' (pson) is invalid for report, u                                                                                        sing default (b64_zlib_yaml)
Debug: report supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml raw yaml; using b64_zlib_yaml
```

Comment: Run puppet with `--debug` and paste the output please. That may give more clues.

Comment: have added the debug message to the question....

Comment: Why not use `hiera` instead? You can have custom facts if you need to using `facter-dot-d` or directly `/etc/facter/facts.d` if using a recent `facter`

Comment: I am using ruby script to pick the class parameters from DB , as I am gonna build a custom UI on top of it. I am not sure if Hiera supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your YAML output lost some `-` and Puppet can't recognize it as a YAML file.
Maybe it should like this?

```
---
classes:
  puppet-agent.cs1cloud.internal:
    tmp_dir: /tmp
    tomcat_home: /tmp/tomcat6
```

Comment: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html have refered this link and it clearly says array syntax cannot be used for parameterized classes. So I believe the yaml output that i construct is correct.

Comment: maybe you use the wrong node name. it should be `puppet-agent.cs1cloud.internal` instead of `tomcat_install`. i should just comment your question, but i don't have the privilege, sorry.

Comment: yaml consists of the class name("tomcat_install") and params ("tmpd_dir","tomcat_home").Node name is automatically detected by the puppet once the test command is run.